# Spanning Sets in Inner Product Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n$ be a spanning set (in particular a basis) in an inner product space $V$. Prove that

a) If $(x, v) = 0$ for all $v$ in $V$, then $x = 0$.

b) If $(x, v_k) = 0$ for every $k$, then $x = 0$.

c) If $(x, v_k) = (y, v_k)$ for every $k$, then $x = y$.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Math.SE.  Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) (linked at the top of every page).  In particular, here's [how to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) (show what you've tried, don't just copy a problem from the textbook), and here's [how to format math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

a) One appropriate choice of $v$ suffices. Try $v=x$.

b) Write $x=\lambda_1v_1+\ldots+\lambda_nv_n$ and use the bilinearity of the inner product when computing $(x,x)=(x,\lambda_1v_1+\ldots+\lambda_nv_n)$.

c) Apply b) to $x-y$ instead fo $x$.

Comment: could you possibly be a little more explicit in the explanation? I'm still rather confused on how to solve this problem.

Comment: @user72195  How can I be more explicit in (a), to get started?

Comment: What does setting v=x actually do?

Comment: @user72195 It does $(x,x)=0$. Now $(x,x)=\|x\|^2$. So?

Comment: then x must be 0. Does anything need to be considered about v though? Such as, what is the difference between creating (x,x) vs. (v,v)?

Comment: @user72195 The statement reads: for a fixed $x$, if $(x,v)=0$ for all $v$, then $x=0$. The variable is $v$, not $x$. So you set $v$ equal to $x$, and you conclude that $x=0$ as desired.

Comment: so for part (b) I have computed (x,x) withe the bilinearity, but what is the point of doing so?

Comment: @user72195 If you did right, you should find $(x,x)=0$.

Comment: or am I then to substitute x for all the v1,...,vn's, which then will result in rewriting as (x,x)=y1[[x]]^2+...+yn[[x]]^2 (my y's being the lamda's) and then using the same point as problem a where x then has to be 0?

Comment: and in the sum of products I have written, x must be 0 because initially we wrote x as a linear combination where lamda cannot be equal to 0?

Comment: @user72195  No. This does not make sense. This time, in (b), $x$ is given and the $v_j$'s are given too. Since the latter span the space, we can write $x$ as a linear combination of them. Then $(x,x)=(x,\sum_  \lambda_jv_j)=\sum \lambda_j(x,v_j)=\sum 0=0$.